# Deducing facts from a set via a predicate by metaprogramming

Tags: prolog, metaprogramming

Suppose I have a set of Literals (represented as a list for instance) and a predicate specified dynamically, what I want is to produce a set of literals that contains all the previous ones in addition to the ones that can be deducted by applying the predicate to the set.

An example, having defined the predicate

```
pred(A, B) :- base(A, B).
pred(A, C) :- base(A, B), pred(B, C).
```

and supposing such a signature for the predicate

```
deduce_set(+Set, +Pred, ?DeducedSet)
```

the following statement holds (is true):

```
deduce_set([base(a,b), base(a,c), base(b,d), base(d, e)],
           pred/2,
           [base(a,b), base(a,c), base(b,d), base(d,e), pred(a,d), pred(a,e), pred(b,e)]
          ).
```

What is the most efficient and general way to do so? I've been thinking about something like:

- asserting all literals in Set
- call Pred
- if it succeeds assert its head
- collect all the asserted facts in the resulting set and put into a list

isn't there a better way?

**UPDATE** This solution, better defined by CapelliC, by using metaprogramming can't cope with vars in the set under Object Identity. Any workaround for this?

Comment: Are you trying to populate `DeducedSet` with a completed list (closure) of `Set` under (dynamically defined) rules of inference for predicate `Pred`?  In this case `DeducedSet` will always consist of the (initial) list `Set` (which perhaps consists of terms with various functors) followed by a tail consisting of new terms for functor `Pred`.  Finding the closure under such rules of inference would probably be facilitated by introducing an accumulator argument.

Comment: Yes I am, But why an accumulator shall be more efficient in this case?

Comment: What I have in mind is that an accumulator makes it easy to construct the `DeducedSet` until no further inferences are possible, and then "return" the already assembled list.  Primarily I was asking if you want "closure" or simply a single pass revision to your `DeducedSet`.

Comment: I've understood the easyness of programming, I'd like to get also an efficient solution to find a closure and possibly one to cope with vars under OI

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use findall/3 (or better, [findall](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=findall/4)/4), avoiding some problem to discriminate (for instance) what instances of pred/2 you will need to remove before retrying the deductive step.

```
deduce_set(Base, Pred/Arity, Res) :-
    functor(P, Pred, Arity),

    % how to 'undo' this without a description?
    % retractall(base(_,_)),

    setof(F-A, M^(member(M, Base), functor(M, F, A)), Desc),
    maplist(retractdesc, Desc),

    maplist(assertz, Base),

    findall(P, P, All),
    append(Base, All, Res).

retractdesc(F-A) :-
    functor(P, F, A),
    retractall(P).
```

I'll would add also a description of Base elements, to know what to clear before running (of course could be obtained using `setof(F-A,M^(member(M,Base),functor(M,F,A)),Desc)` )

```
pred(A, B) :- base(A, B).
pred(A, C) :- base(A, B), pred(B, C).

test :-
    deduce_set([base(a,b), base(a,c), base(b,d), base(d, e)], pred/2, R),
    R = [base(a,b), base(a,c), base(b,d), base(d,e), pred(a,d), pred(a,e), pred(b,e)].
```

Note that test/0 will fail, because the return set doesn't match the expected list.

```
?- test.
base(a,b)
base(a,c)
base(b,d)
base(d,e)
pred(a,b)
pred(a,c)
pred(b,d)
pred(d,e)
pred(a,d)
pred(a,e)
pred(b,e)
false.
```

Generally, I would suggest to use Datalog for your task, as the informal description seems suspiciously similar. See [DES](http://www.fdi.ucm.es/profesor/fernan/DES/) for a 'free to use' and feature rich system.

Comment: Thanks for pointing to Datalog, but I'm required to use Prolog only. To retract all the elements from the Set I guess it is sufficient to call: 
    retract_set(Set) :-
        member(Literal, Set),
        retract(Literal),
        fail.
    retract_set(_).

Comment: This solution (metaprogramming in general I guess) shows a problem when I have not ground literals in my set and I assume OI (Object Identity). For instance [base(X,Y), base(X,Z)] shall lead to pred(X,Z)

Comment: It's a difficult theme. I posted a 'naive' answer, especially because you demanded for `most efficient and general way`. I think 'Datalog' evaluation could be the right answer, but in an answer we could just try to implement the *naive* algorithm, and that also can be rather difficult. And optimizing it become of course a large and difficult task.

Comment: I guess I could ground all the literals preserving a const-var association, apply this method then use the association to revert to the original vars. It adds a bit of complexity though